# Find entre subArrays en Mongoose?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

llevo tiempo que no puedo resolver esto, tengo mis modelos que son los siguientes:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoosePagniate = require('mongoose-paginate-v2'); // Para topic controllers
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Modelo de respuestas
const AnswerSchema = Schema({
  content: String,
  code: String,
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  user: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
});

mongoose.model('Answers', AnswerSchema);

// Modelo de COMMENT
const CommentSchema = Schema({
  content: String,
  code: String,
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  answers: [AnswerSchema],
});
mongoose.model('Comment', CommentsSchema);

// Modelo de topic
const TopicSchema = Schema({
  title: String,
  content: String,
  code: String,
  lang: String,
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  comments: [CommentSchema],
});
// Cargar paginacion para topic controllers
TopicSchema.plugin(mongoosePagniate);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Topic', TopicSchema);
```

Estoy intentando llegar primero a el user para usar el objectId del usuario y poder borrar los comentarios por userId, le estoy pasando la siguiente ruta con el userId por postman:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/comment/topic/5ff60535be168f170c332186
```

y en el controlador intento llegar con un find pero sin resultado, quiero obtener primero todos los comments para borrarlos con el userId que le pase, despues quiero llegar a answers para hacer lo mismo, pero no he tenido resultado, serian tan amables de guiarme porfavor les agradeceria de antemano, aqui uno de mis intentos fallidos en el controller:

```
let userId = req.params.userId;
    Topic.find()
      .populate("user")
      .populate("comments.user")
      .exec((err, topic) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(500).send({
            message: "error en la peticion",
          });
        }
        if (!topic) {
          return res.status(500).send({
            message: "no existe el tema",
          });
        }
        Topic.find({ "comments.user": userId }).exec((err, comment) => {
          return res.status(200).send({
            comment,
          });
        });
      });
```

mi modelo de user

```
"use strict";

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
// esquemas de mongoose y definir propiedades
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = Schema({
  name: String,
  surname: String,
  aptitudes: String,
  acerca: String,
  lenguajes: String,
  facebook: String,
  instagram: String,
  twiter: String,
  linkedin: String,
  email: String,
  password: String,
  image: String,
  role: String,
  ban: String,
});
// Eliminar password de cualquier objeto json que nos devuelva una peticion
UserSchema.methods.toJSON = function () {
  var obj = this.toObject();
  delete obj.password;
  return obj;
};

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Comment: Donde esta tu modelo User?

Comment: hola, pudiste solucionarlo ?

Comment: @HanielBaez ya puse el modelo de usuario

Comment: @Enzo aun no puedo solucionarlo

Comment: pude llegar iterando a user del comentario, pero no creo que sea la mejor forma de hacerlo, ademas cuando igualo el user con el userId que le paso, no me permite borrarlos

Comment: puedes subir el controlador donde lo iteras ?

Comment: ya mismo lo subo @Enzo

Comment: ya esta lo puse como respuesta @Enzo

Comment: Hola @MiguelAngel, esntoces lo quedeseas es eliminar todos los comentarions y respuestas de un usuario, conociendo su _id? Correcto?

Comment: correcto @HanielBaez aprovechando el user de cada comment y answer

Comment: En este caso entiendo que lo mejor seria cambiar todo el esquema, segun entiendo cada Topic puede tener un numero infinito de Comments y estos a su vez pueden tener Answer, el problema esta en que los documentos tienen un limite de 16 MB. Espero que este articulo puede ayudarte con el Schema https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-subset-pattern

Comment: lo que entiendo es que me recomiendas usar un documento por cada uno?, es decir, uno para topics, otro para comments, y el otro para answers?

Answer (score 0):

@Enzo aqui esta mi iteracion

```
 getComments: function (req, res) {
    const userId = req.params.userId;
    Topic.findOne({ 'comments.user': userId }).exec((err, topic) => {
      const comment = topic.comments;
      comment.forEach((comments) => {
        if ((comments.user = userId)) {
          console.log(comments);
        }
      });
      comment.remove();// aqui no se borran
      
      return res.status(200).send({
        status: 'success',
        comment,
      });
    });
  },
```